# IE 9 error getElementbyId: Object required

Tags: javascript, vbscript

for some reason, VBS below works like a charm in IE 8, but in IE9 on both of my Laptops 
I get Object Required at `.getElement`.

How can I fix this please.

```
WScript.Quit Main

Function Main
  Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.Navigate "http://desistream.tv/en/index.shtml"
  Wait IE
  With IE.Document
    .getElementByID("login_username").value = "myuser"
    .getElementByID("login_password").value = "mypass"
    .getElementByID("frmLogin").submit
  End With
End Function

Sub Wait(IE)
  Do
    WScript.Sleep 500
  Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy 
  Do
    WScript.Sleep 500
  Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy 
End Sub

Sub IE_OnQuit
  On Error Resume Next
  WScript.StdErr.WriteLine "IE closed before script finished."
  WScript.Quit
End Sub
```

**edit**

this is what I got so far in JScript

```
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.Run("Chrome www.desistream.tv", 10, true);
WScript.Sleep(500);
```

Comment: Haven't seen VBS in like forever. Why not just re-do it in JavaScript, I'll be for sure more compatible.

Comment: I don't know how to :(. I tried.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly with this piece of code?

Comment: it will login automatically to the website with my username and password. it works in IE8.

Comment: I haven't used VBS in years so I might not be the best to answer this question. I would suggest you take a look at the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript) and experiment to do this in JavaScript. It'll be worth the investment. VBS is hardly used in front-end dev anymore, probably only on some intranet stuff and MS applications.

Comment: @elclanrs It looks like he is doing this on his machine, running it in wscript, not using IE to render this as part of some HTML markup.  The script is launching IE for him on his local PC, which is where the confusion may be coming from.

Comment: Oh I see... Well , the actual login part where he grabs the elements and submits the form can be done in JS no problem. I guess to launch the site he could use NodeJS or a simple bash/cmd script. As for the problem, I've read somewhere about IE9 failing to interpret VBS if not in compatibility mode. @Mowgli: Try switching to compatibility mode and see if it works.

Comment: @elclanrs dude you are awesome... how did you know it will work in compatibility mode?

Comment: @Mowgli: I think it might be because IE9 dropped support for deprecated VBS features that are probably still available in old IE. There's a way to always trigger compatibility mode if that's what you want but I would again suggest doing it in JS.

Comment: I still need to learn to write about script in JScript.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the right names. The names you have given are the Name property, not the ID, so:

```
.getElementByID("login_username").value = "myuser"
.getElementByID("login_password").value = "mypass"
```

Should be:

```
.getElementByID("username").Value = "myuser"
.getElementByID("pass").Value = "mypass"
```

Comment: No, that is not the problem, I have tried that already, and what I have works already on IE8.

Comment: let me try with compatibility mode and with your code, but looks like problem is with compatibility mode to begin with.

Comment: I just tried both condition and they both work if compatibility mode is on. thanks